# Setting minimum and maximum auxiliary variables in PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am new to LP and I am trying to solve a toy problem to allocate cargo in 3 trucks. Each cargo has 2 attributes, price and weigh and each truck can hold 1 cargo each time. I want to maximize the overall price sum of the allocated cargo in all trucks while setting a constraint that the difference between the maximum and minimum allocated weight in any of the trucks can't be over 50 kg.

I tried the following problem definition in PuLP using auxiliary max and min variables for the weight constraint.

```
import pulp

# Example toy data
cargo = {
   "truck1":{
      "c1":{
         "price":100,
         "weight":20
      },
      "c2":{
         "price":150,
         "weight":10
      },
      "c3":{
         "price":90,
         "weight":30
      },
      "c4":{
         "price":500,
         "weight":80
      }
   },
   "truck2":{
      "c5":{
         "price":50,
         "weight":10
      },
      "c6":{
         "price":100,
         "weight":80
      },
      "c7":{
         "price":200,
         "weight":150
      },
      "c8":{
         "price":50,
         "weight":30
      }
   },
   "truck3":{
      "c9":{
         "price":100,
         "weight":50
      },
      "c10":{
         "price":200,
         "weight":200
      }
   }
}

# Create a problem variable:
prob = pulp.LpProblem("Cargo", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Decision variables
truck_allocation_vars = {truck: pulp.LpVariable.dicts("cargo", cargo[truck], 0, 1, pulp.LpBinary) for truck in cargo}

# Constraint: Only one cargo can be chosen for each truck
for truck in truck_allocation_vars:
    prob += pulp.lpSum(list(truck_allocation_vars[truck].values())) == 1

# Objective function: Maximize price
prob += pulp.lpSum([cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['price'] * truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx] for truck_idx in truck_allocation_vars for cargo_idx in truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx]])

# This is where things to wrong ...
# I need to figure out what is the maximum and minimum weight of the allocated cargos
# So I can subsequently add the weight constraint
max_weight = pulp.LpVariable("max_weight", cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
min_weight = pulp.LpVariable("min_weight", cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
for truck_idx in truck_allocation_vars:
    for cargo_idx in cargo[truck_idx].keys():
        prob += (max_weight >= int(cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['weight']) * truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx])
        prob += (min_weight <= int(cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['weight']) * truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx])

# TODO:
# Add weight constraint once max and min weight are correct
# prob += (max_weight - min_weight) < 50

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Print the solution
for truck_idx in truck_allocation_vars:
    for cargo_idx in truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx].keys():
        if pulp.value(truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx]) == 1:
            print(f"Cargo {cargo_idx} in truck {truck_idx} with price {cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['price']} and weight {cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['weight']}")

print(pulp.value(max_weight))
print(pulp.value(min_weight))
```

The maximum variable is correctly set at the end of solve but the minimum variable sticks at 0 (which is a valid solution, just not the one that I want). I have tried a few things (ie. adding lower bound, modifying the cost function to add min_weight) but I haven't managed to find something that works. Most of the times it tells me the problem is infeasible but I assume this is due to a wrong setup. What would you do?

Answer (score 2):

The missing piece to your LP puzzle is a "Big M" constraint to work with the minimum.  (Google it or see any LP textbook).

When you are trying to capture the minimum, you are doing this (where `x` is a binary variable indicating selection):

```
my_min <= x[j] * val[j].    for all j
```

The problem there is that when `x[j]` is zero, this picks up a zero!  The solution is to introduce a suitably large constant, so that when the selection variable is zero, it is a meaningless large number:

```
my_min <= x[j] * val[j] + (1 - x[j]) * M
```

Make a little "truth table" to verify you understand what is going on there if that is confusing.

#### Code:

```
import pulp

# Example toy data
cargo = {
   "truck1":{
      "c1":{
         "price":100,
         "weight":20
      },
      "c2":{
         "price":150,
         "weight":10
      },
      "c3":{
         "price":90,
         "weight":30
      },
      "c4":{
         "price":500,
         "weight":80
      }
   },
   "truck2":{
      "c5":{
         "price":50,
         "weight":10
      },
      "c6":{
         "price":100,
         "weight":80
      },
      "c7":{
         "price":200,
         "weight":150
      },
      "c8":{
         "price":50,
         "weight":30
      }
   },
   "truck3":{
      "c9":{
         "price":100,
         "weight":50
      },
      "c10":{
         "price":200,
         "weight":200
      }
   }
}

M = 300  # suitably large, greater than max of weights.

# Create a problem variable:
prob = pulp.LpProblem("Cargo", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Decision variables
truck_allocation_vars = {truck: pulp.LpVariable.dicts("cargo", cargo[truck], 0, 1, pulp.LpBinary) for truck in cargo}

# Constraint: Only one cargo can be chosen for each truck
for truck in truck_allocation_vars:
    prob += pulp.lpSum(list(truck_allocation_vars[truck].values())) == 1

# Objective function: Maximize price
prob += pulp.lpSum([cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['price'] * truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx] for truck_idx in truck_allocation_vars for cargo_idx in truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx]])

# This is where things to wrong ...
# I need to figure out what is the maximum and minimum weight of the allocated cargos
# So I can subsequently add the weight constraint
max_weight = pulp.LpVariable("max_weight", cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
min_weight = pulp.LpVariable("min_weight", cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
for truck_idx in truck_allocation_vars:
    for cargo_idx in cargo[truck_idx].keys():
        prob += max_weight >= cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['weight'] * truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx]
        prob += min_weight <= cargo[truck_idx][cargo_idx]['weight'] * truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx] \
                               + (1 - truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx]) * M

# TODO:
# Add weight constraint once max and min weight are correct
prob += (max_weight - min_weight) <= 50

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

for truck_idx in cargo:
   for cargo_idx in cargo[truck_idx]:
      if truck_allocation_vars[truck_idx][cargo_idx].varValue > 0.1:  # it is selected
         print(f'load {truck_idx} with {cargo_idx}')

print(f'weight delta is: {max_weight.varValue - min_weight.varValue}')
```

#### Output:

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                700.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

load truck1 with c4
load truck2 with c6
load truck3 with c9
weight delta is: 30.0
```

Comment: Overall I like this approach and I would prefer it over mine. Note that I believe it'll only work if the weight range is used as an upper bound. If it's used as a lower bound, there's nothing stopping `max_weight` from taking arbitrarily large values that don't meet up with the weights in the input dataset.

Comment: @Reinderien.  Thanks.  It would be an odd context if there were a "minimum weight delta", but of course that would require a simple reformulation.

Comment: @AirSquid it works like a charm. Thank you very much for the intuitive explanation!

Comment: @Reinderien interesting point

Answer (score 1):

Certainly feasible. If you don't use the big-M approach, then you can use binary selection variables - one for each truck-cargo pair:

```py
import pulp

cargo = {
   'truck1': {
      'c1': {'price': 100, 'weight': 20},
      'c2': {'price': 150, 'weight': 10},
      'c3': {'price': 90, 'weight': 30},
      'c4': {'price': 500, 'weight': 80},
   },
   'truck2': {
      'c5': {'price': 50, 'weight': 10},
      'c6': {'price': 100, 'weight': 80},
      'c7': {'price': 200, 'weight': 150},
      'c8': {'price': 50, 'weight': 30},
   },
   'truck3': {
      'c9': {'price': 100, 'weight': 50},
      'c10': {'price': 200, 'weight': 200},
   },
}


def cartesian(name: str) -> dict[str, list[pulp.LpVariable]]:
    return {
        truck_name: pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name=name,
            indices=(
                (truck_name, cargo_name)
                for cargo_name in cargos.keys()
            ),
            cat=pulp.LpBinary,
        )
        for truck_name, cargos in cargo.items()
    }


allocations = cartesian(name='alloc')
min_assigns = cartesian(name='minassign')
max_assigns = cartesian(name='maxassign')

min_weight = pulp.lpSum(
    pulp.lpDot(
        assigns,
        [
            props['weight']
            for props in cargo[truck_name].values()
        ],
    )
    for truck_name, assigns in min_assigns.items()
)
max_weight = pulp.lpSum(
    pulp.lpDot(
        assigns,
        [
            props['weight']
            for props in cargo[truck_name].values()
        ],
    )
    for truck_name, assigns in max_assigns.items()
)

# Maximize price
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='Cargo', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
prob.setObjective(
    pulp.lpSum(
        pulp.lpDot(
            cargo_allocs,
            [
                props['price']
                for props in cargo[truck_name].values()
            ],
        )
        for truck_name, cargo_allocs in allocations.items()
    )
)

'''
n min-assignments, binary
n max-assignments, binary
sum(all min-assignments) = 1
sum(all max-assignments) = 1
each min-assignment <= corresponding cargo-assignment
each max-assignment <= corresponding cargo-assignment
min-weight = min-assignment dot weights
max-weight = max-assignment dot weights
For every minassign, minassign dot weight within each truck >= minassign * weight 
'''

# For both min and max, exactly one must be assigned
prob.addConstraint(
    pulp.lpSum(assigns for assigns in min_assigns.values()) == 1
)
prob.addConstraint(
    pulp.lpSum(assigns for assigns in max_assigns.values()) == 1
)

for truck_name, cargos in allocations.items():
    # Only one cargo can be chosen for each truck
    prob.addConstraint(pulp.lpSum(cargos) == 1)

    # The min and max weights must observe the weights in this group
    weight = pulp.lpDot(
        cargos,
        (
            props['weight']
            for props in cargo[truck_name].values()
        ),
    )
    prob.addConstraint(weight >= min_weight)
    prob.addConstraint(weight <= max_weight)

for cargos, mins, maxes in zip(allocations.values(), min_assigns.values(), max_assigns.values()):
    for alloc, amin, amax in zip(cargos, mins, maxes):
        # Min and max selection must follow cargo assignment
        prob.addConstraint(amin <= alloc)
        prob.addConstraint(amax <= alloc)

# Upper limit to widest weight range
weight_range = 50
prob.addConstraint(max_weight - min_weight <= weight_range)

prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

for truck_name, cargo_allocs in allocations.items():
    for (cargo_name, props), alloc in zip(
        cargo[truck_name].items(),
        cargo_allocs,
    ):
        if alloc.value() > 0.5:
            print(
                f"Truck {truck_name} "
                f"with cargo {cargo_name:3} "
                f"and price {props['price']} "
                f"and weight {props['weight']}",
            )

print('Min weight on', next(iter(
    a
    for assigns in min_assigns.values()
    for a in assigns
    if a.value() > 0.5
)))
print('Max weight on', next(iter(
    a
    for assigns in max_assigns.values()
    for a in assigns
    if a.value() > 0.5
)))
print('Min weight:', min_weight.value())
print('Max weight:', max_weight.value())
print('Weight range:', max_weight.value() - min_weight.value(), '<=', weight_range)
```

```
Objective value:                700.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.01
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Truck truck1 with cargo c4  and price 500 and weight 80
Truck truck2 with cargo c6  and price 100 and weight 80
Truck truck3 with cargo c9  and price 100 and weight 50
Min weight on minassign_('truck3',_'c9')
Max weight on maxassign_('truck2',_'c6')
Min weight: 50.0
Max weight: 80.0
Weight range: 30.0 <= 50
```

Comment: this solution is surely above my current knowledge of LP but very interesting to see how you solved it. Am I right to assume that having that many assignment variables would make the solution time much slower if my number of trucks & cargo increase a lot?

Comment: Possibly, but you'd want to test it out.